# How do I show current users in a channel in a panel on the right in irssi

Tags: irssi

How do I show current users in a channel in a panel on the right in irssi?

I have tried googling for this but could not find anything. The screenshot here: http://irssi.org/themefiles/mursu.png shows what I am referring to.

I did think it was part of the theme logic but upon activating a theme it has only changed the colours.

I am new to irssi and would appreciate the xchat-like interface of showing the users without the need to type /names .

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

irssi can't do it out of the box, but you can use the nicklist script to achieve the desired effect. [See this entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/irssi#irssi_with_nicklist_in_tmux) in the ArchWiki for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I currently use screen , if I create a tmux window within a screen session will the cause any problems?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't think they're meant to be used together, but you can always give it a try. Otherwise, the script does have a "screen" mode, so you can use it like that, it's just less convenient than using tmux.

Comment: tmux within tmux might pose a problem, screen within tmux won't, tmux within screen won't, tmux within another tmux (even with a screen in between) might also cause problems.